# for elixir, vscode's outline can't list defp function after adding `private do`

Tags: visual-studio-code, elixir

package `private` has been used for unit-testing defp function.
But in vscode the functions in the `private do ... end` scope can't be listed.
Is it possible to solve it or just accept it?

[private module reference](https://hexdocs.pm/private/Private.html)

private package
[image: private scope function]

outline view
[image: outline view image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `private` library is a straightforward *AST* transformation that basically traverses the *AST* within the `private/1` block and [substitutes `defp` with `def` in test env](https://github.com/pragdave/private/blob/master/lib/private.ex#L64-L70).

Unfortunately, *ElixirLS* is not capable of showing the *expanded AST* as it becomes *after* compilation, it uses its own simple parser and hence it does not see the expanded *AST*. So yeah, without the explicit modifications of *ElixirLS* and/or *VSCode* plugin it’s impossible to see the expanded *AST*. Neither would you see any injected by `use Foo` code, etc.

---

Despite the package being originally created by Dave Thomas, I would *strongly discourage* its usage at all though. It has two major drawbacks:

- testing of private functions is plain wrong, they are implementation details, and testing the implementation details brings more harm than profit;
- testing the code which **is not** the same as one running in production is meaningless and dangerous.

The former rule above should be obvious, the latter requires some elaboration. [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) *differently* treats and even compiles private and public functions. Private functions might be inlined, what, generally speaking, changes the preemptive concurrency context switching by *ErlangVM*. In some rare cases, this might lead to drastically hard to catch randomly raising concurrency bugs and race conditions. Yes, this is extremely unlikely, but it’s still possible.

That said, you’d better stop testing private functions at all rather than trying to make *VSCode* show screwed up *AST*.

Comment: BTW, if you insist on the necessity to test private functions (which I, again, do not recommend,) the functionality of `private` might be easily mimicked with module attributes instead of `private/1` blocks. I might provide a PR to `private/1` to support it.

Comment: It is related to module size. If module size is big and it is complex, lots of function will be private, unit test will face the private function test problem. If the module size is small, and the complex module breaks down to many smaller modules, and every smaller module's public function, even these function only used internally.

Comment: What's the meaning of PR? Is it customized attribute?

Comment: Pull Request implementing this feature.